# form not creating new entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a form to add a transporter:
I have app/views/transporters/new.html.erb that calls a template,app/views/_form.html.erb that looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@transporter) do |f| %>
  <% if @transporter.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@transporter.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this transporter from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @transporter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id_number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :id_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Add transporter', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back to all transporters', transporters_path, class: "btn" %>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the create action in my transporters controller:

```
  def create
    @transporter = Transporter.new(transporter_params)
  end

private 
def transporter_params
      params.require(:transporter).permit(:name, :phone, :id_number)
    end
```

When I click Add transporter the form doesn't go anywhere. What do I have wrong?

Update:
this is my routes file:

```
Cowsnhills::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :transporters

  resources :deliveries

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

When I click submit the form reloads but the entries will not show on my transporters index, here is that code:
transporters controller method:

```
  def index
    @transporters = Transporter.all
  end
```

and transporters index:

```
<h1>Listing transporters</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @transporters.each do |transporter| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= transporter.name %></td>
        <td><%= transporter.phone %></td>
        <td><%= transporter.id %></td>
        <td><%= f.link_to_add "Add a delivery", :deliveries %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show transporter details', transporter %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit transporter details', edit_transporter_path(transporter) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete transporter', transporter, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Transporter', new_transporter_path, class: "btn" %>
```

Also there's a transporter has_many deliveries and a velivery belongs_to transporter association going on

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not go anywhere" ? You have a 404, and the same page is rendered ?

Comment: Can you post your routes for the transporter resource?

Comment: I just installed your app locally and I created a new transporter without any issues. Have you checked your logs to see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 @transporter = Transporter.new(params[:transporter])
```

or

```
@transporter = Transporter.new(params["transporter"])
```

check my last comment to save it.

Comment: OP uses strong parameters.

Comment: @billy yes i have seen that but there is no harm to use params[:transporter] to check making fields as attribute_accessible to test if there is any error or not. seems like form is ok.

Comment: okay that doesn't work. Also when i enter numbers for phone and id fields the form submits but nothing shows on transporters index (that should show all transporters). When i enter string for phone and id the form won't submit at all

Comment: please check if you have html5 enable browser which will automatically not able to submit your form if you do not have the correct data for the field type

Comment: @connorLeeck please check in rails server what is going on and also in the db. is there any roll back by any validation.

Comment: The code is on github here: https://github.com/thebenedict/cowsnhills under the associations branch

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh There is no more `attr_accessible` in Rails 4. OP uses Rails 4.

Comment: @depa you are r8. connor please check the error in rails development server.

Comment: in the create action write transporter = Transporter.new(transporter_params) and then transporter.save and check

Comment: @connorleech or else try transporter = Transporter.create(transporter_params) in the create action else data will not be saved

Answer (score 1):

You just create a new object with your params from the form in your create action, but you don't save it.
add @transporter.save to your create action.