# nothing happens when I click submit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I have a create action in a transporters controller

```
 def create
    @transporter = Transporter.new(transporter_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @transporter.save
        format.html { redirect_to @transporter, notice: 'Transporter was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @transporter }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @transporter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    @transporter.save
    end
private
def transporter_params
      params.require(:transporter).permit(:name, :phone, :id_number)
    end
```

But when I try to submit the form using this form:

```
<%= form_for(@transporter) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id_number %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :id_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Add transporter', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Nothing happens. The form does not reload and the data is not saved to the database. Why isn't my form submitting?

Comment: Please check your javascript console. There would be some js errors on page.

Comment: Can you add you transporter model code? Also, what do you get after form submision - error page, empty page?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question twice. I left you a comment in the other one saying I ran your app and it's saving objects just fine. Your problem lies somewhere else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803765/form-not-creating-new-entries